# How to pass value from php to jquery function my code is given below

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

The following is my code. Without passing value working well.

```js
function add(name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="add("Aftab");">
  Send
</button>
```

Comment: Closing as a typo. You're mixing your quotes. Use `onclick="add('Aftab');"` - or better yet, an unobtrusive event handler instead of the 90s relic that is the `on*` event attributes.

Comment: Thanks sir ...Problem solved.....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="add('<?php echo $name; ?>');">
  Send
</button>

function add(name){
  alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added in this way value to function in this way which is wrong.
The issue is due to double quotes.

> onclick="add("Aftab");"

Use this

> onclick="add('Aftab');"

or

> onclick='add("Aftab");'

```js
function add(name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="add('Aftab');">
  Send
</button>
```